# Parsing XML Using Python

Tags: xml, elementtree

i'm using Python 2.5 and WinXP.
i am parsing xml file as below:

```
<Test>
<Default_Config>
  <LINK>{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6}</LINK> 
  <Lanestat>{1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 8, 5: 10, 6: 12}</Lanestat> 
  </Default_Config>
  </Test>
```

however when i print out, the output is as below:

```
(None, '{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6}')
(None, '{1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 8, 5: 10, 6: 12}')
```

Question: How to modify my code so that Link and Lanestat appears instead of None.
tq
Code:

```
import elementtree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("dict1.xml")
doc = tree.getroot()


for elem in doc.findall('Default_Config/LINK'):
    #print elem.get('LINK'), elem.text
    a=elem.get('LINK'), elem.text
    print a

for elem in doc.findall('Default_Config/Lanestat'):

    #print elem.get('LINK'), elem.text
    a=elem.get('LINK'), elem.text
    print a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("dict1.xml")
doc = tree.getroot()

for elem in doc.findall('Default_Config/LINK'):
    a = elem.tag, elem.text
    print a

for elem in doc.findall('Default_Config/Lanestat'):
    a = elem.tag, elem.text
    print a
```

=>

```
('LINK', '{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6}')
('Lanestat', '{1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 8, 5: 10, 6: 12}')
```

Comment: now i want to extract info from lanestat 1 to obtain a 2. however, this is a tuple. i manage to do it using below code: for elem in doc.findall('Default_Config/Lanestat'): a=elem.tag, elem.text print a print type(a) b=a[1] print type(b) c=eval(b) print type(c) print c[1]. is there any elegant way of doing this? tq

Comment: @maximus: ask a new question, and I'm sure someone will come to the rescue!

Answer (score 0):

try using a=elem.tag instead of a=elem.get('LINK')

```
import elementtree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("dict1.xml")
doc = tree.getroot()

for elem in doc.findall('Default_Config/LINK'):
    a=elem.tag, elem.text
    print a

for elem in doc.findall('Default_Config/Lanestat'):
    a=elem.tag, elem.text
    print a
```